# ShowTextAligned is not outputting text accurately

Tags: itext

I'm using the code snippet below.  I would expect the text to be exactly one inch apart but it's not.  What am I doing wrong?

```
Dim outputFile As String = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "test.pdf")
    Using fs As New FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)
        Using doc As New Document(PageSize.LETTER)
            Using writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs)
                doc.Open()

                'This creates two lines of text using the iTextSharp abstractions
                '   doc.Add(New Paragraph("This is Paragraph 1"))
                '  doc.Add(New Paragraph("This is Paragraph 2"))

                'This does the same as above but line spacing needs to be calculated manually
                Dim cb As PdfContentByte = writer.DirectContent
                cb.SaveState()
                cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK)
                cb.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED), 12.0F)
                cb.BeginText()
                ' rlm - dimensions are from the bottom
                cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, "This is cb1", 20, 20, 0)
                cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, "This is cb2", 20, 92, 0)
                cb.EndText()
                cb.RestoreState()
                doc.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are measuring things but I just printed your sample out at actual resolution and compared it with a ruler and their baselines are indeed one inch apart.

If you are measuring on a computer screen you are going to run into problems. Windows-based machines generally (although this is changing) run at 96 DPI, so if you view your test on a computer screen at 100% and try to measure it you'll get about 4/3 of an inch (96/72). So called "hi-DPI" settings and devices are becoming more commonplace so there's no guarantee what a screen will actually measure to.

[image]